# About the ceiling function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $⌈x⌉$ be the ceiling function of $x$. Given that $a<b$ are fixed real numbers find all $x$ satisfying the following conditions:

1) $a<⌈x⌉<b$

2) $a≤⌈x⌉<b$

3) $a<⌈x⌉≤b$

4) $a≤⌈x⌉≤b$

I have no idea to start.

Comment: are $a$ and $b$ integers?

Comment: @FullofDill: where and $a$ and $b$ are real numbers

Comment: Find values of $a$ and $b$ as functions of $x$ which work equally well for $x=0.5$ and $x=1$ and see if the result generalizes for any $x$.

Comment: If $x<y$ does it not also follow that $x\le y$? So if you answer $(1)$ have you not also answered $(2),\,(3)$ and $(4)$?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales: The question is for $x$ when $a$ and $b$ are fixed.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify the question by stipulating "Given that $a<b$ are fixed real numbers find all $x$ satisfying the following conditions:"

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales: Ok. It is edited. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are integers then $\alpha < \lceil x \rceil \le \beta \implies \alpha < x \le \beta$.

In order to find the solution of your problem, we try to transform the given conditions into $\alpha < \lceil x \rceil \le \beta$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are integers.

To this end, we note that 
$$a < \lceil x \rceil \iff \lfloor a \rfloor<\lceil x \rceil,$$
$$a \le \lceil x \rceil \iff \lceil a \rceil-1<\lceil x \rceil,$$
$$\lceil x \rceil < b\iff \lceil x \rceil \le \lceil b \rceil-1,$$
and
$$\lceil x \rceil \le b\iff \lceil x \rceil \le \lfloor b \rfloor.$$

With the above-mentioned relationships, we arrive at

- $a < \lceil x \rceil < b \implies \lfloor a \rfloor < x \le \lceil b \rceil-1,$
- $a \le \lceil x \rceil < b \implies \lceil a \rceil-1 < x \le \lceil b \rceil-1,$
- $a < \lceil x \rceil \le b \implies \lfloor a \rfloor < x \le \lfloor b \rfloor,$
- $a \le \lceil x \rceil \le b \implies \lceil a \rceil-1 < x \le \lfloor b \rfloor.$

Comment: $\lfloor a\rfloor =\lceil a\rceil-1$

Comment: @kingW3 Put $a=1$

Comment: Yeah you're right,the right hand formula looked kinda strange.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=\alpha_0.\alpha_1\alpha_2\ldots$ in its decimal form, where $\alpha_0\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots$ are single digits. Then to satisfy the inequality $a<\lceil x\rceil$, the ceiling of $x$ has to be at least $\alpha_0+1$, so $x>\alpha_0=\lfloor a\rfloor$.

Satisfying $\lceil x\rceil<b$ is alittle bit more tricky. If we similarly write $b=\beta_0.\beta_1\beta_2\ldots$, then we have two cases.

- Case 1: $b$ is not integer. Then the integer part of $x$ can be as high as $\beta_0-1=\lfloor b\rfloor-1$ (or anything less, of course), because then $\lceil x\rceil\le\beta_0<b$. And $x=\beta_0$ also works, because $\lceil x\rceil=\lceil\beta_0\rceil=\beta_0<b$. But any number of the form $y=\beta_0.\beta_1'\beta_2'\ldots$ with nonzero fractional part wouldn't work, because its ceiling is $\lceil y\rceil=\beta_0+1>b$. In summary, $x\le\lfloor b\rfloor=\lceil b\rceil-1$ in this case.
- Case 2: $b$ is an integer, i.e. $b=\beta_0$. Then the maximal possible value of $x$ is $\beta_0-1$, so that $\lceil x\rceil\le\beta_0-1<b$. So in this case we again find that $x\le\lceil b\rceil-1$.

The bottom line is that $a<\lceil x\rceil<b$ is satisfied for all $x$ in $\lfloor a\rfloor<x\le\lceil b\rceil-1$ (where we interpret it as the empty set when the left boundary is higher than the right boundary).

I'm sure this solution can be shortened to avoid considering different cases, but this is the first thing that came to my mind. And you can handle the other inequalities similarly.

**Note:** this solution has been edited since I posted it originally, because the original solution was wrong. Sorry…

Answer (score 0):

All $x$ that map to the same $\lceil x\rceil=n$ are in the range

$$(n-1,n],$$ i.e.

$$n<x+1,x\le n.$$

Then

$$a<\lceil x\rceil<b$$ is achieved by

$$a<n<x+1,x\le n<b$$
or

$$a-1<x<b.$$

Equality on the left is never achieved, equality on the right is preserved.

Comment: So you are saying that $a-1<x$ implies $a<\lceil x \rceil $, which does not hold for $x=0.7$ and $a=1.5$.

Comment: @MathLover: not at all, I say that $a<\lceil x\rceil$ implies $a-1<x$, which is what the OP is asking. For example, with $x=1.01$ and $a=1.99$ we do have $a<\lceil x\rceil$ and $a-1<x$.

Comment: I agree that $a < \lceil x \rceil \implies  x> a-1$ as does $a < \lceil x \rceil \implies  x>a-20000$.